# Including count combinations with null value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I have one dataset, and am trying to list all of the combinations of said dataset. However, I am unable to figure out how to include the combinations that are null. For example, Longitudinal? can be no and cohort can be 11-20, however for Region 1, there were no patients of that age in that region. How can I show a 0 for the count?

Here is the code:

```sql
SELECT "s_safe_005prod"."ig_eligi_group1"."site_name" AS "Site Name", 
       "s_safe_005prod"."ig_eligi_group1"."il_eligi_ellong" AS "Longitudinal?", 
       "s_safe_005prod"."ig_eligi_group1"."il_eligi_elcohort" AS "Cohort",
       count(*) AS "count"
FROM "s_safe_005prod"."ig_eligi_group1"
GROUP BY "s_safe_005prod"."ig_eligi_group1"."site_name", 
         "s_safe_005prod"."ig_eligi_group1"."il_eligi_ellong", 
         "s_safe_005prod"."ig_eligi_group1"."il_eligi_elcohort"
ORDER BY "s_safe_005prod"."ig_eligi_group1"."site_name", 
         "s_safe_005prod"."ig_eligi_group1"."il_eligi_ellong" ASC, 
         "s_safe_005prod"."ig_eligi_group1"."il_eligi_elcohort" ASC
```

Comment: FYI [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided. You are far better off aliasing your objects in the `FROM` and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids the use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version, and makes your code much more succinct and readable. Certainly here, if you used aliases and used that to qualify your columns, your code would be about much more readable.

Comment: cross join "all cohorts" and "all Longitudinal?" tables , left join your dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a cross join across the unique values from each of the three grouping fields to create a set of all possible combinations. Then left join that to the counts you have originally and coalesce null values to zero.

```
WITH groups AS
(
SELECT a.site_name, b.longitudinal, c.cohort
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT site_name FROM s_safe_005prod.ig_eligi_group1) a,
     (SELECT DISTINCT il_eligi_ellong AS longitudinal FROM s_safe_005prod.ig_eligi_group1) b,
     (SELECT DISTINCT il_eligi_elcohort AS cohort FROM s_safe_005prod.ig_eligi_group1) c
), 
dat AS
(
SELECT      site_name, 
            il_eligi_ellong AS longitudinal, 
            il_eligi_elcohort AS cohort, 
            count(*) AS "count"
FROM        s_safe_005prod.ig_eligi_group1
GROUP BY    site_name, 
            il_eligi_ellong, 
            il_eligi_elcohort
)
SELECT  groups.site_name,
        groups.longitudinal,
        groups.cohort,
        COALESCE(dat.[count],0) AS "count"
FROM groups 
    LEFT JOIN dat ON    groups.site_name = dat.site_name 
                    AND groups.longitudinal = dat.longitudinal
                    AND groups.cohort = dat.cohort;
```

Comment: I now need to narrow the results down to when "yes" is selected for a patient in another dataset. I've tried a million things but nothing is working. Is there a simple solution for that using your previous response? @flexyourdata

Comment: If you open another question with the right details and sample data, I'm confident you'll get the help you need.